# Why does `skaffold build` with docker always produces different digest each run

Tags: skaffold

Why does `skaffold build` with docker always generate a different docker image digest each time it is run despite the fact that everything has been cached - I turned on verbosity=debug while running sth like `skaffold build --interactive=false --file-output=build/artifacts.json -v=debug --push=false` and observe that the digest from the docker build output

```
#20 exporting to image
#20 exporting layers
#20 exporting layers 0.4s done
#20 writing image sha256:5f4fafd725d610c56909a808fe578b82075639c0fff38998449346c8859c4951 done
#20 naming to docker.io/library/bore:latest done
#20 DONE 0.4s
```

is always different each build run. The logs show that skaffold is running this command behind the scenes:

```
DEBU[0002] setting DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 for docker build for artifact "bore" since it targets platform "linux/amd64"  subtask=bore task=Build
DEBU[0002] Running command: [docker build .. --file /Users/nseesillapachai/applied-ai/bore/Dockerfile -t bore:latest --platform linux/amd64]  subtask=bore task=Build
```

This is not the case when I tried running the above docker command without skaffold - repeated runs still yield the same image digest - been stuck for hours trying to figure this out now so would really appreciate any help/pointer! Thank you!